# Как заставить питон прекратить менять \ на \\ в локаторе?

Tags: python, html, кодировка, xpath, экранирование

Есть локатор `//span[translate(text(), "\u00a0", " ")="{блабла}"]`, который проверяет элементы на странице. Доходя до элемента с неразрывным пробелом тест падает, потому что при выводе в консоли локатор приобретает вид `//span[translate(text(), "\\u00a0", " ")="{article_title}"]`. Как оставить символ `\` в локаторе?

Пробовала варианты с `r"\u00a0"` и `"\\u00a0"`, не работают.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Вы смотрите не строку, а её отображение в виде строкового литерала (обратите внимание на кавычки по краям), и то, что он отображает строку с экранированными спецсимволами — это абсолютно правильное поведение, иначе строковый литерал был бы сломан и не соответствовал бы настоящему содержимому строки

Comment: Лучше покажите [mcve] кода с тем, что где там у вас падает, чтобы мы могли найти ошибку и указать вам на неё

Comment: 'Didn`t find element with locator: "//span[translate(text(), "\\u00a0", " ")="тут название тайтла"]"'
Остальные тайтлы локатор находит нормально, проблема именно в том, где есть неразрывной пробел.

Comment: Код врядли чем-то поможет, проблема именно в локаторе.

Comment: Ну тогда мы вряд ли чем-то поможем. Лишь ещё раз отмечу, что вы смотрите строковый литерал с экранированными спецсимволами, а реально внутри строки хранится ровно один \ (если вы конечно, не сломали что-нибудь где-нибудь ещё, но вы же не хотите показывать код, а мы не телепаты и угадать не можем)

Comment: Я бы с радостью, но NDA есть NDA. Как бы вы тогда посоветовали составить локатор, чтобы обойти проблему неразрывного пробела?

Comment: Поскольку кода нет, я могу лишь гадать на кофейной гуще, а моя кофейная гуща предлагает просто написать этот самый неразрывный пробел как есть без всяких u00a0 (он же не является спецсимволом, зачем его экранировать вообще). Ну или экранировать в xml-стиле `&#160;` но я не знаю будет ли это работать

Comment: Не очень поняла про "просто написать" можете пожалуйста пояснить? Тайтлов несколько сотен, эти неразрывные пробелы могут быть где угодно и в любом месте тайтла, а могут и не быть.